# Normalization of data within ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have my data as

```
melted.df <- structure(list(organisms = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Botrytis cinerea", "Fusarium graminearum", 
"Human", "Mus musculus"), class = "factor"), types = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("AllMismatches", 
"mismatchType2", "MismatchesType1", "totalDNA"), class = "factor"), 
    mutations = c(30501L, 12256L, 58357L, 366531L, 3475L, 186907L, 
    253453L, 222L, 24906L, 2775L, 247990L, 12324L, 4395L, 25324L, 
    77862L, 1862L, 112217L, 163117L, 100L, 17549L, 1057L, 20331L, 
    18177L, 7861L, 33033L, 288669L, 1613L, 74690L, 90336L, 122L, 
    7357L, 1718L, 227659L, 635951L, 229493L, 868052L, 2418724L, 
    65833L, 1081903L, 1339758L, 4318L, 59387L, 15199L, 2134229L
    )), row.names = c(NA, -44L), class = "data.frame")
```

The values totalDNA in type column indicates total DNAs in the data whereas mismatches are the mutations. I would like to normalize this data based on totalDNA values and plot it. The way I am plotting right now doesn't give me the accurate picture of the data as todalDNA inflates the whole Y-axis and other three types(mismatchType2, mismatchesType1 and AllMismatches) are not properly visible with respect to totalDNA. What would be the better way to plot this? Should I first calculate the percentage? or Perhaps do log scaling? Thanks for helping me out.

```
ggplot(melted.df, aes(x = types, y = mutations, color=types)) +       
  geom_point()+
  facet_grid(.~organisms)+
  xlab("Types")+
  ylab("Mismatches")+
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a log scale?

```
ggplot(melted.df, aes(x = types, y = mutations, color=types)) +       
  geom_point()+
  facet_grid(.~organisms)+
  xlab("Types")+
  ylab("Mismatches")+
  # ylim(c(90,130))+
  scale_y_log10()+ #add log scale
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank())
```

How would you normalise on total DNA? Would you use the (geometric) mean?